# Termination plan for EC2

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

I need to create an Termination plan for all the EC2 instance that i have ,.

i.e . If the server is stopped for 7 consecutive days then only that ec2 can be terminated. if not it cant.

Any idea on how to do this ? i am thinking for doing it via Cloud watch events rule by pulling all the stopped instance for 7 days greater and its target is via lambda so it will check the rule and terminate it. Will this work ? if Yes how ? Ideas please.

```
import boto3
ec2client = boto3.client('ec2')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
  instancesWithEvent = ec2client.describe_instance_status(
    Filters=[
      {
        'Name': 'event.code',
        'Values': [
            'instance-reboot', 'system-reboot', 'system-maintenance', 'instance-retirement', 'instance-stop' 
        ]
      },
    ],
    MaxResults=1000,
    IncludeAllInstances=False
  )

  instancesToTerminate=[]
  for index in instancesWithEvent['InstanceStatuses']:
    instancesToTerminate.append(index['InstanceId'])
  if len(instancesToTerminate) > 0:
    print("Instances to terminate: %s " % (', '.join(instancesToTerminate)))
    ec2client.terminate_instances( DryRun=False, InstanceIds=instancesToTerminate )
  else:
    print("No instances with events found.")
  return()
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you please edit your question and tell us what you have tried and what specific difficulty you are facing? Did you try running the above code? If so, what problem are you facing? Are you able to identify the instances that have been stopped for 7 days? Have you been able to terminate the instances? Thank you.

Comment: I tried using cloud watch events . pulling in the list of instance that are stopped for last 7 days. this lambda is for terminating. so as per the cloud watch event rule it takes the list and executes this lambda . i am assuming this will work. but not sure. Need an idea how to go through this ?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your requirements are:

- Find instances that have been **Stopped** for longer than a given period
- Terminate them

Based on [Reddit: How can I see how long 'stopped' EC2 instances have been stopped for?](https://www.reddit.com/r/aws/comments/4owe13/how_can_i_see_how_long_stopped_ec2_instances_have/) it would appear that the "stop date" can be extracted from the `StateTransitionReason`:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --filter "Name=instance-state-name,Values=stopped" --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].[InstanceId, StateTransitionReason]' --output text
i-xxxxxxxx  User initiated (2016-05-23 17:27:19 GMT)
i-xxxxxxxx  User initiated (2016-02-22 18:23:21 GMT)
i-xxxxxxxx  User initiated (2015-12-09 16:10:24 GMT)
i-xxxxxxxx  User initiated (2016-05-23 17:27:19 GMT)
```

Thus, your program would need to:

- Call `DescribeInstances()` to obtain a list of instances
- Find the instances that are stopped and extract the date from the `StateTransitionReasonStateTransitionReason` field
- If the date is beyond the desired period, then call `TerminateInstances()`

Thus, it could be something like this:

```py
import boto3
import re
from datetime import datetime

TERMINATION_AGE = 7

ec2_client = boto3.client('ec2', region_name='ap-southeast-2')

# Get a list of stopped instances
instances = ec2_client.describe_instances(Filters=[{'Name': 'instance-state-name', 'Values': ['stopped']}])

for reservation in instances['Reservations']:
    for instance in reservation['Instances']:

        # StateTransitionReason might be like "i-xxxxxxxx User initiated (2016-05-23 17:27:19 GMT)"
        reason = instance['StateTransitionReason']
        date_string = re.search('User initiated \(([\d-]*)', reason).group(1)
        if len(date_string) == 10:
            date = datetime.strptime(date_string, '%Y-%m-%d')

            # Terminate if older than TERMINATION_AGE
            if (datetime.today() - date).days > TERMINATION_AGE:
                ec2_client.terminate_instances(InstanceIds=[instance['InstanceId']])
```

Be careful — it can be dangerous to write code that terminates instances. You should test it before deploying! You might also want to add additional safeguards such as only terminating instances with a particular tag.